# Gradient fill empty in for loop

Tags: javascript, css, createjs

I'm drawing buttons on createjs canvas that have gradient fill and stroke. The number of buttons are drawn inside a for loop. Each section, as you will see in the fiddle, is drawn separately via function. but only the first function run draws the correct fill. The subsequent calls only draws the gradient stroke [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jacobsultd/wqu4nzdq/9/)

```
for (i = 0; i < db.length; i++) {
        var btn = db[i];
        var sdb = btn.split("_");
        var blabel = sdb[0];
        var battrib = sdb[1]; 
        var bval = sdb[2]; 
        var sid = sdb[3]; 
        var tick = sdb[4]; 
        var cptn = sdb[5];
        var imageType = sdb[6]; 
        var buttonSize = 90 + 10;



        var bttn = new c.Shape();
        bttn.graphics.beginLinearGradientFill([grad1, grad2], [.2, 1], 0, 0,0,50 ).setStrokeStyle(3).beginLinearGradientStroke([grad2, grad1], [.2, 1], 0, 0,0,50 ).drawRoundRect(x, y, 85, 35,5);

        var label = new c.Text(blabel);
            label.font = font;
            label.color = '#000';
            label.x = x+8;
            label.y = y+6;


        m1.addChild(bttn, label);

        x+= buttonSize;
    }s.update();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working to me. Is it perhaps that you forgot to offset your buttons, so you're only seeing the first one? `bttn.y = i*40`

https://jsfiddle.net/gskinner/wqu4nzdq/12/

Comment: From my example, the gradient worked on the first call..  But look at remainder of buttons. They are solid white.  That color is the second gradient color used in the function.. The remainder of buttons should render the exact same way..

Comment: I can't see that in any browser I tested in. However, by changing the y position, it worked fine.